# Can I cross the road?

Tags: traffic

Scenario (see mostly accurate diagram below):

- normal road with traffic lights for cars (horizontal)
- no traffic lights for cars (vertical)
- horizontal traffic lights are red (cars stopped)
- cars going up (vertical) or going down (vertical) and no cars turning up from horizontal lane (ie safe to cross)
- no pedestrian lights (horizontal)
- pedestrian lights (vertical)
- location: Canada

Question:

- Can I legally cross (and not be considered jaywalking) in the scenario if I am at the top right and want to go to the top left? (circled woman in diagram, assume cyclist is not there)

[image: diagram]

Comment: Is this a hypothetical question or do you really know of such an intersection where traffic is only half-controlled?

Comment: @brhans This is actually the case near where I live. The horizontal road is a road that is much more used than the vertical road (like the diagram).

Comment: I have seen roads with similar layouts, although only .rarely

Answer (score 1):

I think that the rule is to look both ways and cross only when no one is coming. Also, since this is a crosswalk, turning traffic and traffic approaching you is supposed to yield.